# Splitting a string in Java on ";", but not on "\\;"

Tags: java, regex

In Java I try try to use the `String.split()` method splitting a string on `";"`, but not on `"\\\\;"`. (2 back-slashes followed by a semi-colon)

Ex: `"aa;bb;cc\\;dd;ee\\;;ff"` should be split into;

```
aa

bb

cc\\;dd

ee\\;

ff
```

How do I accomplish this using a regular expression?

Markus

Comment: (What about on `\\\\;`?)

Comment: Splitting on \\\\; splits _only_ on the "\\;" (2 back-slashes followed by a semi-colon). I do not want to split there.

Comment: It might be easiest to simply split on ';' and add a ';' back to the end of every part that ends with '\\'

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077432/how-do-i-split-a-string-using-a-regular-expression-that-excludes-an-escaped-versi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
"aa;bb;cc\\;dd;ee\\;;ff".split("(?<!\\\\);");
```

(?<!...) is called a "zero-width lookbehind". In English, you're splitting on all `;` characters that are **NOT** preceded by a double slash, without actually matching the double slash. The quadruple slash is to escape backslashes to the regex parser. The actual regular expression used in the split would then read:

```
(?<!\\);
```

Comment: this needs quoting of the `\` i think.

Comment: I don't know... I'm confused about all the backslashes :-) I checked my code, it matched correctly...

Comment: I also think it must be 8 \, this gives 4 on the regex level and amounts to 2 real backslashes.

Comment: @Ingo: But we don't want to amount to 2 real backslashes, just 1. Unless, the OP has a mistake in his question...

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, as he quoted his example string. OTOH he says "2 backslashes followed by semicolon".

Answer (score 5):

This is called negative lookbehind and the syntax is like `(?<!a)b`. This matches on any b that isnt precended by an a. You would want something like:

```
(?<!\\\\);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a code example with . as separator:

```
String p = "hello.regex\\.brain\\.twister";
System.out.println( p );
for (String s : p.split( "(?<!\\\\)\\.", -1 )) {
  System.out.println( "-> "+ s );
}
```

Will Ouptut:

```
hello.regex\.brain\.twister
-> hello
-> regex\.brain.\twister
```