# Splitting string expression into tokens

Tags: java, regex, string, split

My input is like

```
String str = "-1.33E+4-helloeeee+4+(5*2(10/2)5*10)/2";
```

i want the output as:

```
1.33E+4
helloeeee
4
5
2
10
2
5
10
2
```

But I am getting the output as

```
1.33, 4, helloeeee, 4, 5, 2, 10, 2, 5, 10, 2
```

i want the exponent value completely after splitting "1.33e+4"

here is my code:

```
    String str = "-1.33E+4-helloeeee+4+(5*2(10/2)5*10)/2";
    List<String> tokensOfExpression = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] tokens=str.split("[(?!E)+*\\-/()]+");
    for(String token:tokens)
    {   
         System.out.println(token);
         tokensOfExpression.add(token);
    }
    if(tokensOfExpression.get(0).equals(""))
    {
         tokensOfExpression.remove(0);
    }
```

Comment: what you want seems crazy. Why would you reduce 5*2 to 5 and 2? You just lose the *? If you're going to do that you may as well just replace all the operations characters with delimiters then call split.

Comment: Are you trying to write a calculator? If you are, what is `helloeeee`? What exactly are you trying to do with them?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682021/splitting-a-string-in-java-on-but-not-on helps

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a single regular expression, because of the ambiguities introduced by FP constants in scientific notation, and in any case you need to know which token is which without having to re-scan them. You've also mis-stated your requirement, as you certainly need the binary operators in the output as well. You need to write both a scanner and a parser. Have a look for 'recursive descent expression parser' and 'Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm'.Resetting the digest is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I would first replace the E+ with a symbol that is not ambiguous such as

```
str.ReplaceAll("E+","SCINOT");
```

You can then parse with [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), replacing the `SCINOT` symbol when you need  to evaluate the number represented in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] tokens=str.split("(?<!E)+[*\\-/()+]");
```

Comment: Thanks Aditi.its working fine but i have to look for string part ending with "e/E" ex:helloe+4 should come as helloe 4

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to achieve the result with Matcher

```
    String str = "-1.33E+4-helloeeee+4+(5*2(10/2)5*10)/2";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d*E[+-]?\\d+|\\w+").matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

prints

```
1.33E+4
helloeeee
4
5
2
10
2
5
10
2
```

note that it needs some testing for different floating point expressions but it is easily adjustable